# Web Scraping "Exception in thread Thread-1 (periodic):" error - Python

Tags: python, json, web-scraping

So I needed to look for a certain element in a JSON file I generated from web scraping. I've tried looking for some elements such as, "time_pretty", "ip_address" etc. It all printed out well, but some of the elements that I tried printing such as "organization", printed maybe half of the list, then after that it gave me this error.

```
Exception in thread Thread-1 (periodic):
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\threading.py", line 1009, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\threading.py", line 946, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "d:\Visual Studio Code\TechCellar\scraper3.py", line 33, in periodic
    organization = i["organization"]
KeyError: 'organization'
```

So this is the main part of my code. I won't include the params due to confidentiality :).

Libraries

```
import requests
import json
from threading import Thread
from timed_count import timed_count
```

Code

```
def periodic():
    for count in timed_count(60):
        response = requests.get(api_url, params=params)

        # Execute code here exactly every 60 seconds
        if (response.status_code == 200):
            data = response.json()

            arr = []
            for element in data:
                time = element["dates"][0]["items"]
                for i in time:
                    time2 = i["ip_address"]
                    organization = i["organization"]
                    # arr.append(organization)
                    print(organization)

            data_file = open("visitors_list", "w")
            json_formatted_str = json.dump(data, data_file, indent=4)

            data_file.close()

        else:
            print("Error connecting to Clicky.com API.\nError: " +
                  response.status_code)


thread = Thread(target=periodic)
thread.start()
```

Here https://i.stack.imgur.com/sUpiu.png https://i.stack.imgur.com/RaEkR.png there is the JSON file

and here https://i.stack.imgur.com/YdTYx.png, https://i.stack.imgur.com/9ajKk.png there is the output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is difficult to say for sure without looking at the JSON file. I would check the index of the element in the `items` array where the the key lookup fails and ensure that it contains the `organization` key. If the keys are inconsistent across elements, you need better error handling to prevent this issue from occurring.

```py
for element in data:
    time = element["dates"][0]["items"]
    for index, i in enumerate(time):
        time2 = i["ip_address"]
        organization = i["organization"]
        print(f"{index}: {organization}")
```

Comment: Hello Ramzi. I tried your method, and it turns out that some parts of the data from the JSON file don't contain the "organization" field. Now, what can I do to print all of the elements of the "organization" field, and exclude the ones that doesn't contains "organization"?

Comment: Okay, so I tried "Try Except" and it worked! Thank you for this! Helped me in debugging.

Comment: @AndreLacra you can use the filter method to exclude those elements like so:

for element in filter(lambda item: "organization" in item, time):
.....